# выбор родителя элемента с именем из хеша с фильтром по классу

Tags: javascript, jquery

- Нужно взять div c именем, которое идёт после # в ссылке по которой
  пришёл
- взять всех его прямых родителей и выбрать только тот, который с классом .title
- сделать по нему клик

я в jquery пока нивзубногой и у меня типа вот так получилось:

```
 $(($(div[name=document.location.hash]).parent())filter('.title')).click();
```

...наверное ещё '#' нужно отрезать

подскажите как правильно построить конструкцию?

пример в html:

```
<div class="spoiler closed">
 <div class="title">
  Заголовок спойлера
 </div>
 <div class="contents">
  <div id="opis-el">
   <div id="opis-pic"><img ...>картинка</div>
   <div id="opis-txt" name="one">описание элемента</div>
   <div id="opis-sl">примечание</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

ссылка по которой пришёл: `http://test.domain.ru/test/#one`

Comment: Добавь пример html

Comment: добавил пример в html

Comment: но тут же `title` не является родителем для элемента с name="one"

Comment: да, и правда... не является, но он предыдущий его родителю..
кажется как-то можно выбрать его соседа и на него и кликнуть
но уже очень помогло!

Comment: @Grundy или может быть взять все соседние дивы и выбрать для клика только ближайший с таким классом т.е. первый попавшийся)

Comment: Данный ответ делает то что вы хотите, единственное вместо `siblings` можно `prev` использовать но это не сущестевенно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
$('div[name=' + window.location.hash.replace('#','') + ']').closest('.contents').siblings('.title').click();
```

Comment: не подходит под добавленный html

Comment: я думал там должно быть что-то типа parent()

Comment: @S3rjioTT, `parent` смотрит только на первый уровень, так что тут действительно нужен `closest`

Comment: @Grundy, увы, html был добавлен уже после моего ответа. А в изначальном вопросе говорилось о родителе.

Comment: Поэтому стоит отредактировать ответ :-)

Comment: Конкретно для текущей задачи тогда действительно можно использовать parent() т.е. подняться на уровень и взять предыдущий элемент.

Comment: @S3rjioTT, `parent` вернёт вам элемент `<div id="opis-el">`. Я отредактировал ответ с учетом вашей разметки.

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро Да! Всё работает в точности как и хотелось! Премного благодарен!!

Comment: @S3rjioTT, тогда стоит принять ответ  как верный :)